# Loop through the elements of a set in elm

Tags: elm

Can I loop through elements of a `Set` in **Elm**? Or at least convert the `Set` to a `List`?
There exists `Set.fromList`, but I don't find any `List.fromSet` or something similar.
I know there is no for loop in Elm, but I want to go through the elements recursively like I do in case of list:

```
        interate lst = 
        case lst of
            [] -> False
            x::xs -> ...
```

but for a `Set`.

Comment: "Looping" isn't something you do in Elm. You typically either `map` or `fold` over a collection, producing either some other collection or a single value. There are function for doing both in `Set`, as well as `toList` and `fromList`. This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `Set.toList` for this.